# Kernel headers not found

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install virtualbox, but fail to install my kernel headers.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

outputs

`linux-headers-3.13.0-042stab108.5 not found'`

what can I do?

(Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the generic headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: this does install some headers, and I coult install the driver. Nevertheless I can's start the driver, I get the error:    modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab108.5/modules.builtin.bin'

Comment: You might need to follow this up by making sure you install the generic kernel as well. Looks like the headers are linux-generic, but your currently booted kernel is not. Try : sudo aptitude install linux-generic